# Use of brackets bug in Swig template for node.js

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

As it seems swig template [is not able to do some basic stuff](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/537) such as having two conditions within brackets inside an `if` statement, I was wondering how you guys will deal with this without having to duplicate code:

```
{% if( absence.approved and absence.rejected) or (demo.demo and demo.test) %} 
      whatever
{% endif %}
```

Right now that breaks the view because [Swig doesn't support it](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/522)...

Answer (score 1):

remove the brackets and it should work fine

```
{% if absence.approved and absence.rejected or demo.demo and demo.test %} 

whatever

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Works fine if you fix the location of your first parenthesis:

```
> var swig = require('swig')
> swig.render('{% if( foo and bar) or (baz and bop) %}yep{% endif %}');
Error: Unexpected tag "if( foo and bar) or (baz and bop)" on line 1.
> swig.render('{% if (foo and bar) or (baz and bop) %}yep{% endif %}');
''
>
```

Comment: Still not working with things like `if (a.name == 'Pending or (status.name == 'Approved' and absence.only_admin != 1))`